# Javascript does not recognize the same class on another div

Tags: javascript

I am studying JS, I created this gallery and I am trying to make a modal that takes the selected image. I can only do this in the first div, the others don't work.

Here's my code on CodePen
https://codepen.io/KaioRocha/pen/rNNRzEp

```
    // Get the modal
    var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");

    // Get the image and insert it inside the modal - use its "alt" text as a caption
    var img = document.querySelector(".myImg");
    var modalImg = document.getElementById("img01");
    var captionText = document.getElementById("caption");
    img.onclick = function(){
        modal.style.display = "block";
        modalImg.src = this.src;
        captionText.innerHTML = this.alt;
    }

    // Get the <span> element that closes the modal
    var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

    // When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
    span.onclick = function() {
        modal.style.display = "none";
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[**`querySelector()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) ***returns the*** **first element** within the document that matches the specified selector, or group of selectors.

You should use [**`querySelectorAll()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) to target all the images with the specified *class*, then loop through them to attach the event individually like the following way:

```
var modalImg = document.getElementById("img01");
var captionText = document.getElementById("caption");
var imgList = document.querySelectorAll(".myImg");
Array.from(imgList).forEach(function(img){
  img.onclick = function(){
    modal.style.display = "block";
    modalImg.src = this.src;
    captionText.innerHTML = this.alt;
  }
});
```

Comment: You should put `var modalImg = document.getElementById("img01");
  var captionText = document.getElementById("caption");` outside the loop.

Comment: @StackSlave, you are right, updated the answer, thanks:)

Comment: Thank dudes! You rock! Works like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

`document.querySelector(".myImg");` will select only the first `.myImg`. Every other will stay intact.

You can select them all with `document.querySelectorAll(".myImg");`, then run them trough loop and add event listener on every one of them.